# Rails DB Seeding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, rake

For some reason, the food_id field in 'ratings' isn't populating when I run the seed.rb file below.  Can somebody help me figure out why?

Seed file contains the following lines:

```
Food.create(:id => 1, :description => 'Stonyfield Farm Yomommy 4oz. Strawberry')
OverallRating.create(:score => 0, :count => 1, :food_id => 1)
```

Code for Food and Rating are as follows:
    class OverallRating < Rating
      belongs_to :food
    end

```
class Food < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :overall_rating
end

class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :food
end
```

The rating migration file is as follows:

```
class CreateRatings < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :ratings do |t|
      t.integer :food_id
      t.integer :count
      t.decimal :score
      t.string :type
      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :ratings
  end
end
```

Comment: I have a feeling this is related to the fact that I am using Single Table Inheritance on Rating and OverallRating.  But can't be sure...

Comment: looks like the migration code isn't being highlighted correctly, might want to edit & fix the indentation real quick

Answer (score 0):

how are you invoking the seeds.rb file? You may have to do a `rake db:seed`

Comment: i invoke:
rake db:migrate:reset
rake db:seed

and the result is the same

Answer (score 0):

Is that really the actual code?  I would guess you've got an attr_accessible or attr_protected declaration in Rating/OverallRating that is preventing the option from being set in the instantiated object.

Comment: yes this is the actual code.  I removed all attr_accessible and attr_protected declarations and it still doesn't update...

Comment: Why does this code reference OverallRating when the model here is called Rating?

Can you post the live db schema for these two tables?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hardcoding the `id`, try something like this:

```
food = Food.create(:description => 'blah')
food.create_overall_rating(:score => 0, :count => 1)
```

I just tried your exact method though, and it worked for me without a problem. So perhaps you have something else awry.